# PHP - charset for variables and include

Tags: php, variables, character-encoding, include

I have looked in the existing answers but I'm not able to find this specific situation. Let me know if I am mistaken.

I recently started using PHP. I've created the structure and everything with no problem

Mi index is such index.php and its created with includes:

header

content

footer

I want to make it multi-language and I am creating files so I can define the variables

```
 $lang['TITLE'] = 'Título';
```

I use `echo` to show these variables and they are showing with no problems, even with special characters such  **Título**  BUT at the moment that I am using `include` to load a file **content.html**, I got encodign errors such:

interÃ©s - interés
bÃºsquedas - búsquedas

In other words, when the text is created from an `echo` statement, everything is shown properly, but loading a file using `include`, only the include file is showing errors.

I already tried using CHARSET in so manyways, but, whether the echo result is incorrect or the include result is incorrect.

Las thing I tried is to set the service to standarize UTF-8 encoding with `mb_` but this way it is just not showing the special characters

inter **é** s = inters

Thanks a lot, please let me know what my error is or what can I do.

Comment: We will need a bit more information. First up, where are you changing the character set at? Is the data stored in a DB and retrieved? If you are not changing the character set on the HTML page, you will need to do so with a META tag. If you are using a DB, the DB also needs to have the same character set and the data will more than likely need to be re-inserted. If you are entering the fields through a page to post to the DB, that page needs to have the same charset too.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any difference whether you `include` files or `echo` text. PHP does not do any encoding conversion or handle encodings in any way in these operations. All it does is output the raw text as found in the source code directly, unaltered.

If text from one file works and from another doesn't, that means those files are differently encoded. Save them in the same encoding in your text editor.

*Possibly* you are outputting a different `Content-Type` header in these two files, as HTML tag or otherwise. Check for that remote possibility.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did the trick. I don't know what happened. The solution was exactly the encoding of the files FROM the text editor. I edited an existing file, probably I forgot to change the encoding while translating the document. I really apprecite the quick response